# docker toolboxでimageをsaveする方法

Tags: windows, docker, docker-toolbox

Windows 10 HomeでDocker Toolboxを使っています。

imageをsaveして保存しておきたいのですが、VirtualBox上で動作しているためアクセス禁止になってしまうようです。また、保存する先もわかりません。

imageをファイルに書き出して保存しておく方法はないでしょうか？

↓エラーメッセージ

```
$ docker save image_uwsgi-nginx-flask_full_set:latest > image_uwsgi-nginx-flask_full_set.tar
bash: image_uwsgi-nginx-flask_full_set.tar: Permission denied
```

↓使っているdockerの情報

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:      19.03.5
  API version:  1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.12.12
  Git commit:   633a0ea838
  Built:        Wed Nov 13 07:28:45 2019
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
 containerd:
  Version:      v1.2.10
  GitCommit:            b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:      1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:            3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:      0.18.0
  GitCommit:            fec3683
```

```
VirtualBox 
バージョン 6.1.4 r136177 (Qt5.6.2)
```

Comment: `docker save` について、私の手元で同じエラーが再現できませんでした。また関連 issue も https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/497 くらいしか無さそうです。設定を詳しくしりたいので、`docker version` など関係しそうな情報を質問文に追記いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 情報追記しました。
他に関係ありそうなものはちょっと思いつかないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。たとえば VirtualBox のバージョン情報等や、エラーメッセージの全文などがあると嬉しそうです。前者はバージョンが https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases と揃っているかを気にしています。後者は検索に使いたいです。

Comment: 情報追加しました。VirtualBoxはＰＣを再起動するタイミングでdefaultマシンがよく壊れるため、バージョンが古いことが原因かと思いアップデートをした過去があります。

Answer (score 0):

Docker Toolbox の Docker Quickstart Terminal を使っているのであれば `/c` などにホスト環境のドライブがマウントされているため、そこに `docker save` すればホスト環境に保存されます。

たとえば：

```
nek MINGW64 ~
$ pwd
/c/Users/nek

nek MINGW64 ~
$ docker save piyo:latest > piyo.tar

nek MINGW64 ~
$
```

とすると、ホスト側の `C:\Users\nek` に `piyo.tar` が保存されています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
そのとおりにやってみたいのですが、
Permission denied
になってしまいました。

Comment: ファイルの名前は何にしていますか？

Comment: image_uwsgi-nginx-flask_full_set.tar　です。